# How to use the same iterator twice, once for counting and once for iteration?

Tags: iterator, rust, reset

It seems that an iterator is consumed when counting. How can I use the same iterator for counting and then iterate on it?

I'm trying to count the lines in a file and then print them. I am able to read the file content, I'm able to count the lines count, but then I'm no longer able to iterate over the lines as if the internal cursor was at the end of the iterator.

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let log_file_name = "/home/myuser/test.log";
    let mut log_file = File::open(log_file_name).unwrap();
    let mut log_content: String = String::from("");
    //Reads the log file.
    log_file.read_to_string(&mut log_content).unwrap();
    //Gets all the lines in a Lines struct.
    let mut lines = log_content.lines();
    //Uses by_ref() in order to not take ownership
    let count = lines.by_ref().count();
    println!("{} lines", count); //Prints the count
                                 //Doesn't enter in the loop
    for value in lines {
        println!("{}", value);
    }
}
```

[`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) doesn't have a `reset` method, but it seems the internal cursor is at the end of the iterator after the count. Is it mandatory to create a new [`Lines`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/str/struct.Lines.html) by calling `log_content.lines()` again or can I reset the internal cursor?

For now, the workaround that I found is create a new iterator:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let log_file_name = "/home/myuser/test.log";
    let mut log_file = File::open(log_file_name).unwrap();
    let mut log_content: String = String::from("");
    //Reads the log file.
    log_file.read_to_string(&mut log_content).unwrap();
    //Counts all and consume the iterator
    let count = log_content.lines().count();
    println!("{} lines", count);
    //Creates a pretty new iterator
    let lines = log_content.lines();
    for value in lines {
        println!("{}", value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Calling [`count()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.count) consumes the iterator, because it actually iterates until it is done (i.e. [`next()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next) returns `None`).

You can prevent consuming the iterator by using [`by_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.by_ref), but the iterator is still driven to its completion ([`by_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.by_ref) actually just returns the mutable reference to the iterator, and [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) is also implemented for the mutable reference: [`impl<'a, I> Iterator for &'a mut I`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#impl-Iterator-for-%26mut+I)).

This still can be useful if the iterator contains other state you want to reuse after it is done, but not in this case.

You could simply try forking the iterator (they often implement [`Clone`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html) if they don't have side effects), although in this case recreating it is just as good (most of the time creating an iterator is cheap; the real work is usually only done when you drive it by calling `next` directly or indirectly).

So no, (in this case) you can't reset it, and yes, you need to create a new one (or clone it before using it).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've though about cloning the iterator but I though it's equivalent to create a new one in this case. I understand that the iteration has a cost (either in a `for` or in a `count`), but it has a cost only if I iterate, and I iterate only if I need to. But if iterate again is not possible, I'll create a new iterator.

Comment: `You can prevent consuming the iterator by using by_ref, but the iterator is still driven to its completion` Can you clarify what the purpose of `by_ref` is? I can't exactly tell what `state` there is to "reuse" after it is "done". Once it's done what's left?

Comment: I don't know any good existing example. But, theoretically, [`std::vec::IntoIter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.IntoIter.html) could allow you to reuse the underlying memory by returning it as an empty `Vec` (with the previous capacity).

When iterating manually with `next()` the iterator isn't consumed, and by using `for elem in it.by_ref() { ... }` you get the same - i.e. the iterator is left, with whatever state it has.

Answer (score 11):

The other answers have already well-explained that you can either recreate your iterator or clone it.

If the act of iteration is overly expensive or it's impossible to do multiple times (such as reading from a network socket), an alternative solution is to create a collection of the iterator's values that will allow you to get the length and the values.

This does require storing every value from the iterator; *there's no such thing as a free lunch*!

```
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let log_content = fs::read_to_string("/home/myuser/test.log").unwrap();
    let lines: Vec<_> = log_content.lines().collect();

    println!("{} lines", lines.len());
    for value in lines {
        println!("{}", value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Iterators can generally not be iterated twice because there might be a cost to their iteration. In the case of `str::lines`, each iteration needs to find the next end of line, which means scanning through the string, which has some cost.  You could argue that the iterator could save those positions for later reuse, but the cost of storing them would be even bigger.

Some `Iterator`s are even more expensive to iterate, so you really don't want to do it twice.

Many iterators can be recreated easily (here calling `str::lines` a second time) or be `clone`d. Whichever way you recreate an iterator, the two iterators are generally completely independent, so iterating will mean you'll pay the price twice.

In your specific case, it is probably fine to just iterate the string twice as strings that fit in memory shouldn't be so long that merely counting lines would be a very expensive operation. If you believe this is the case, first benchmark it, second, write your own algorithm as `Lines::count` is probably not optimized as much as it could since the primary goal of `Lines` is to iterate lines.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that the iteration over an iterator has a cost, but as I said to Stefan I iterate throuth only if I need so it's my choice in this case to iterate. But I guess it's in order to discourage us to waste performance by iterate when it's not necessary. So I'll create a pretty new iterator if it's the way that I'm supposed to take.