# Rust: move occurs because has type `ReadDir`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

Tags: rust

In https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html I find very similar example of using references for `String` type, but in my code I got `` move occurs because `*paths_ref` has type `ReadDir`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait ``. What difference with `String`? How I can use `ReadDir` without memcopy there?

```
use std::fs;

const CACHE_ADDR: &str = ".";

fn get_files() -> std::fs::ReadDir {
    fs::read_dir(CACHE_ADDR).unwrap()
}

fn main() {
    let paths: std::fs::ReadDir = get_files();
    let paths_ref = &paths;
    println!("Count: {}", paths_ref.count());
    for path in paths_ref.into_iter() {
        println!("{:?}", path.unwrap().path());
        break;
    }
}
```

`cargo build` error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*paths_ref` which is behind a shared reference
 --> src/main.rs:8:27
  |
8 |     println!("Count: {}", paths_ref.count());
  |                           ^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `*paths_ref` has type `ReadDir`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*paths_ref` which is behind a shared reference
 --> src/main.rs:9:17
  |
9 |     for path in paths_ref.into_iter() {
  |                 ^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because `*paths_ref` has type `ReadDir`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.
error: could not compile `osm-nca-proc`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Comment: The issue is that `count` and `into_iter` consume the iterator, whereas `String::len` takes a reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `fn calculate_length(s: &String) -> usize` takes a reference of String and returns an `usize`, in this case, you own the returned value. When you do `println!("The length of '{}' is {}.", s1, len);`, your println macro trying to use `s1` and `len`. There are no problem with this.

In your function, `fn get_files() -> std::fs::ReadDir` return a `ReadDir` struct, which you have the ownership of this struct, which is okay.

In the following line, you are creating a immutable reference to it `let paths_ref = &paths;`, this is okay.

In the line after that, you are trying to call `paths_ref.count()`, this is not okay. Why? `count` is a method belong to trait `Iterator`, if you look at the definition of `count` method in Iterator, which is `pub fn count(self) -> usize`, it takes the ownership of `self`, and then return a `usize`. What this means is that as soon as you call `count`, the Iterator is consumed and not exist anymore.

Because `path_ref` is a reference of `self`, and it doesn't own the `ReadDir` data, you cannot call on count on it. You can use `paths.count()` which will consume the `paths` variable and return a usize. But note after you call `count` your `paths` variable will not exist anymore and you can't use it in the below context.

In your example, you essentially need to iterate the `ReadDir` twice, one is to get the total count, and the other is to iterate the each element. You can achieve the same thing by using 1 iteration and manually count the total element (like using a counter `i += 1` in each iteration), or you can call `get_files` twice.

In the case you really want to iterate once, you can collect it (into a vec) and then you can use it to get the length and get iteration.

I found a very similar stackoverflow question, you might want to check this one
[How to use the same iterator twice, once for counting and once for iteration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48037128/how-to-use-the-same-iterator-twice-once-for-counting-and-once-for-iteration)